# I'm using express-flash to display the error messages that occurs while login, but getting error: req.flash is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, passport.js, ejs

I'm learning to implement passport.js in nodejs and using express-flash to display the error message.
But I'm getting the error that "req.flash is not a function".

code of app.js after importing the required modules:-

```
app.set("view engine", "ejs")

//  initialize passport
initializePassport(passport)

// importing routes
const loginRoute = require("./routes/Login")
const registerRoute = require("./routes/Register")


// middlewares
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })) // make sure to use bodyParser before the router
app.use("/login", loginRoute)
app.use("/register", registerRoute)
app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}))
app.use(flash())
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())
```

code of login.ejs:-

```
<h1>LogIn</h1>
<% if (locals.messages) { %>
    <%= messages.error %>
<% } %>
<form action="/login" method="POST">
    <div>
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required="true">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="password"> Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required="true">
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>

<a href="/register">Register</a>
```

I tried making the below change in the login.ejs file as:-

```
<% if(messages) {%>
   <%= messages.error%>
<%}%>
```

but in that case I'm getting error that "messages is not defined"

code of login.js:-

```
const express = require("express")
const passport = require("passport")
const router = express.Router()

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render("login")
})

router.post('/', passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/register',
    failureRedirect: '/login',
    failureFlash: true
}))

module.exports = router
```

code to configure passport:-

```
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt")
const Users = require("./user")

async function getUserByEmail(email) {
    console.log(email)
    for (let i = 0; i < Users.length; i++){
        if (Users[i].email === email)
            return Users[i]
    }
    return null
}

async function authenticateUser(email, password, done) {
    try {
        const user = await getUserByEmail(email)

        if (user == null)
            return done(null, false, { message: "No user with that email exists!" })
        if (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password))
            return done(null, user)
        else
            return done(null, false, { message: "Incorrect password!" })
    }    
    catch (err) {
        return done(err)
    }
}

function initialize(passport) {
    //  use LocalStrategy
    passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
        { usernameField: "email", passwordField: "password" }, authenticateUser))
    
    // serialize & deserialize
    // serialize user to store inside of a session
    passport.serializeUser((user,done) => {})
    passport.deserializeUser((id,done) => {})
}

module.exports = initialize
```

I tried to make changes in the ejs file but still its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your `app.js` doesn't demonstrate that you have imported `express-flash`.

Just to be sure, you need to:

```
npm install express-flash
```

then in your `app.js` import it like

```js
const flash = require('express-flash')
```

then use the `flash` middle ware **before** your routes but **after** your session middleware:

```js
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}))
app.use(flash());
app.use("/login", loginRoute)
//...
```

Read [here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) about Express middleware so that you can understand how each middleware is just a phase that typically accesses the request object. Each stage passes the request through to the next stage with `next()` until it either fails or is returned (or hangs if you have errors in the middleware). That will make it easier to grasp where in this process `express-flash` fits in your application.

Comment: Thanks, using `flash` middleware before the routes fixed the issue!
I already imported the `express-flash` in the app.js, actually, I have mentioned above, that in app.js I have pasted the code after importing the required modules.